# Displaying data from SQLite Database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Looking for some info and advice for trying to accomplish setting redundant data in `EditText` fields from an SQLite Database in my app. The main issue is on two of the attribute fields, it seems that SQLite stores and retrieves a default value of 0.0 for fields of the `REAL` type when there is no data present in the database and I would like to try and not set anything for these two fields instead. So I am not sure if it is needing to be addressed and adjusted in the onCreate() of the DBHelper class since I currently have both of these fields set to `real not null` when the database table is created. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is from my `DBHelper` class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
/* All the below will define the column names schema for the database. */
private static final String UID = "id";
private static final String JOINT_ID = "Custom_Joint_Id";
private static final String JT_NUM = "Manufacturer_Joint_Number";
private static final String JOINT_HEAT = "Heat";
private static final String JOINT_LENGTH = "Joint_Length";
private static final String MANUFACTURER = "Joint_Manufacturer";
private static final String WALL_THICKNESS = "Joint_Wall_Thickness";
private static final String JT_DIAMETER = "Joint_Size_Diameter";
private static final String GRADE = "Grade";
private static final String COATING_TYPE = "Joint_Coating_Type";
private static final String COATING_THICKNESS = "Joint_Coating_Thickness";
private static final String LOCATION = "Current_Location";
private static final String CUTS = "Cuts";
private static final String NEW_LENGTH = "New_Length";
private static final String CHILD_PIPE_ID = "Child_Pipe_Id";
private static final String NOTES = "Notes";
private static final String DATE = "Date";
```

The `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        /* Creating the db */
        db.execSQL("create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + JOINT_ID + " text unique not null, " + JT_NUM + " text not null, " + JOINT_HEAT + " text not null, " + JOINT_LENGTH + " real not null, " + MANUFACTURER + " text not null, " + WALL_THICKNESS + " real not null, " + JT_DIAMETER + " real not null, " + GRADE + " text not null, " + COATING_TYPE + " text, " + COATING_THICKNESS + " text, " + LOCATION + " text, " + CUTS + " real null, " + NEW_LENGTH + " real null, " + CHILD_PIPE_ID + " text null, " + NOTES + " text null, " + DATE + " text)");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /* end of try/catch here */
} /* onCreate ends here. */
```

Here is the method in the `DBHelper` class where I am checking the database to see if it contains any data at all or is empty. If data is found, I want to get the most recent record.

```
/*
    This method passes and displays redundant pipe data to the TallyActivity2 activity This pipe data
    normally stays the same after initial tally has happened
     */
    public Pipe displaySomePipeInfo() {
        SQLiteDatabase dbDisplayInfo = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursorDisplayInfo = null;

        String selectCriteriaHighest = "select * from " +TABLE_NAME + " where id = (select max(id) from " +TABLE_NAME+")";
        try {
            cursorDisplayInfo = dbDisplayInfo.rawQuery(selectCriteriaHighest, null);/* Getting the most recent record */

            Pipe pipe = new Pipe(); // Creating an instance of the Pipe class
            if (cursorDisplayInfo != null && cursorDisplayInfo.moveToFirst() && cursorDisplayInfo.getCount() == 0) {
                /*
                Empty database
                I don't want to do anything but just leave since there is no data in the database.
                 */
                cursorDisplayInfo.close();
                dbDisplayInfo.close();
            } else {
                if (cursorDisplayInfo != null && cursorDisplayInfo.moveToLast()) {
                    /*
                    If there is data in the database, I want to display certain attributes for the most recent
                    set of data entered to keep from having to type them all in again
                     */
                    pipe.setJointManufacturer(cursorDisplayInfo.getString(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(MANUFACTURER)));
                    pipe.setWallThickness(cursorDisplayInfo.getDouble(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(WALL_THICKNESS)));
                    pipe.setSizeDiameter(cursorDisplayInfo.getDouble(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(JT_DIAMETER)));
                    pipe.setGrade(cursorDisplayInfo.getString(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(GRADE)));
                    pipe.setCoatingType(cursorDisplayInfo.getString(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(COATING_TYPE)));
                    pipe.setCoatingThick(cursorDisplayInfo.getString(cursorDisplayInfo.getColumnIndex(COATING_THICKNESS)));
                    return pipe;
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursorDisplayInfo != null) {
                cursorDisplayInfo.close();
            }
            dbDisplayInfo.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the app's `TallyActivity2` class where the data collection takes place and I am also making the `redundantPipeInfo()` method to display redundant data in the correct EditText fields.

```
/*
    This method displays redundant pipe data in the EditText fields for certain ones that normally
    remain unchanged once initial tally is started. It is called in the onCreate() activity from
    this class.
     */
    private void redundantPipeInfo(){
        // An instance of the DBHelper class
        DBHelper dbHelperRedunData = null;
        try {
            dbHelperRedunData = new DBHelper(TallyActivity2.this);
            /* calling the method from the DBHelper class and assigning it to instance of the Pipe class */
            mRedundantPipe = dbHelperRedunData.displaySomePipeInfo();

            /*
            Setting the EditText fields of the redundant data
             */
            mEtPipeManufacturer.setText(mRedundantPipe.getJointManufacturer());
            mEtPipeWallThick.setText(String.valueOf(mRedundantPipe.getWallThickness()));
            mEtPipeGrade.setText(mRedundantPipe.getGrade());
            mEtPipeCoatType.setText(mRedundantPipe.getCoatingType());
            mEtPipeCoatThick.setText(mRedundantPipe.getCoatingThick());
            mEtPipeSizeDiameter.setText(String.valueOf(mRedundantPipe.getSizeDiameter()));
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dbHelperRedunData != null) {
                dbHelperRedunData.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am calling the `redundantPipeInfo()` method in the same `TallyActivity2` `onCreate()` method so that it is always present and available every time this activity is started since this is where the data collection takes place.

```
/* Attempting to display any redundant pipe Info here if it exist */
        redundantPipeInfo();
```

My biggest question is how to accomplish this if it is possible. My biggest goal would be to just set a blank EditText for those two fields in particular if they are empty, instead of the SQLite default 0.0 value. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's because you set them as `REAL NOT NULL`. So the database will fill them. And the default value is **0.0**. Try just removing `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Rotwang. I did that as you suggested. I am also getting an NPE error pointing to where I am trying to set the EditText in the calling Activity. For some reason in the DBHelper method `displaysomePipeInfo()` it is making it to the else and trying to set these fields from an empty database I think. I need to track that down now. Thanks

Comment: Still displaying the default value of 0.0 for the fields even after changing my table settings like @Rotwang suggested. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: You have to then uninstall and reinstall your app, in order for the db to be recreated on the very first run.

Comment: @Rotwang. I did just try that. Still defaults to 0.0.

Comment: Then, the last thing you can do to make it work as intended is to add `DEFAULT NULL` to your fields.